# java.sql.SQLException:Could not rollback with auto commit set on (JDBC with OracleConnection ,Weblogic 12c)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, weblogic

technology : Java - JDBC
,Weblogic Server : 12c
,Databse : Oracle 12c

I have recently migrated my weblogic server from 10g to 12c version . On 12c version the below auto commit parameters are set to true by default:

autocommet = true
autoCommitSpecComplaint = true

Because of this , all database transactions are getting committed automatically even though rollback() method is called .

After debugging the java code , I have noticed that auto commit operation is performed right after callableStatement.execute(); method is executed. i.e auto commit is happening before the rollback() method is invoked. and when rollback() method is executed ,java.sql.SQLException:Could not rollback with auto commit set on exception is raised

I have set below parameters on weblogic's Server Start tab.

-Doracle.jdbc.autoComitSpecCompliant=false
-Doracle.jdbc.autocommit=false

But no luck . I am still facing the issue

I have read some articles suggests to use an older OJDBC driver but i don't want to use any older Drivers on Weblogic server

I want to override these parameters on web logic server itself .So please help me to fix this problem

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit

Comment: #GriffeyDog       The same code is used in my application in java .               con.setAutoCommit(false); is already set in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to rollback a database transaction then you must disable automatic commit otherwise all DML queries will be committed immediately. To disable automatic commit please make sure that the following property is set during server start (it's a JVM system property):

> -Doracle.jdbc.autoCommit=false

(note the upper case C)

If you keep getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not **commit** with auto-commit set on

or in the case of rollback

> java.sql.SQLException: Could not **rollback** with auto-commit set on

Then you are still in auto-commit mode.

The property `oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant` should really only be used if you can't disable auto-commit and your code still explicitly calls commit or rollback (<- which would be a bug).